# Can't change "Welcome message", Logo, copyright

Tags: magento2.3, logo, change

I am using Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1 and I have trouble changing the "Wellcome message", the logo, and the copyright.
I have managed to change them once by going on the admin page, then Content->Design->Configuration->Edit.
In Header, if I try to change the logo image or the size or the Welcome message, the changes will not appear on the store website.
I also try to change the copyright in Footer with the same result.
Things I've tried:

- Save Configuration -> Flush Magento cache - in Admin panel
- Save Configuration -> Flush cache storage -> Flush Catalog Images cache -> Flush JavaScript/CSS cache -> Flush Static Files cache - in Admin panel
- magento setup:upgrade -> magento setup:di:compile - in terminal

The messages (Wellcome message and the copyright) and the logo are not changing. Why?

Comment: Try accessing website with query string or another browser

Comment: I've tried that... no change :(

Comment: Are you sure it has been stored as store wise ? Just take a quick look at the settings where it has been saved

Comment: In Design Configuration there is only one record (not 3 as normal): Default - Global; Website - Main Website; Theme Name - Magento Luma. There is where I've made the changes.

Comment: Are you selecting the right view? global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a better answer:
I selected Stores-Settings-Configuration-General-General then in the bottom of the page there is a setting called "Enable Single-Store Mode". After changing that to "No" I could make my changes.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've managed to make the changes by updating the database. I've looked for design/header/welcome and change the value to the message I want. Did the same for design/footer/copyright and for design/header/logo_src.

After that, in terminal:

./magento setup:upgrade

./magento setup:di:compile

Perhaps is not the best way but works for now.

Comment: this is not the right approach these things can be easily changed from the magento backend and if you changes are not visible then this could be the cache issue try to check the changes in private windows

Comment: You must understand, I've tried everything else without result.